# accepting parameters with component as a function in react (quick fix)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, components, react-props

I have the code below:

```
files.map((fl) => <AudioFileListItem key={fl.id} id={fl.id} name={fl.name} />)
```

I call this component in a different file called Test.js which is also a component. I am trying to pass these variables into the component. I was wondering how I could modify AudioFileListItem to accept these variables.

Here is the component rn:

```
function AudioFileListItem() {

  return (
    <div className="AudioFileListItem">
    </div>
  );

}

export default AudioFileListItem;
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use [props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) to pass data across components. checkout the following code

```js
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));

function App() {
    const files = [
        { id: 1, name: "orange" },
        { id: 2, name: "banana" },
        { id: 3, name: "coconut" },
    ];
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div className={"bg-secondary min-vh-100"}>
                {files.map(fl => (
                    <AudioFileListItem key={fl.id} data={fl} />
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

function AudioFileListItem(props) {
    return <div className="AudioFileListItem">{props.data.name}</div>;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
  <div id="root">123</div>
```